# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token < on line 1

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, web

I have a text file with details stored in the following format:

```
Hayden:Australia:200:7800:45
Lara:West Indies:204:10800:47
Gilchrist:Australia:100:12800:45
```

My php code is something like this

```
<?php
    $fields = array("name","country","matches","runs","centuries");
    $file = fopen("players.txt", "r");
    $count = 0;
    $finalArr = array();
    while($players=fgets($file))
    {
        $players = trim($players);
        $temparr = array();
        $arr = explode(":",$players);
        //echo $arr;
        for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
        {   
            $temparr[$fields[$i]] = $arr[i];
        }
        $finalArr[$count] = $temparr;
        $count++;
    }
    fclose($file);
    $return = json_encode($finalArr);
    echo $return;
?>
```

When I try to access it using `JSON.parse`, I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

This is my HTML side code:

```
if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
            {
                var players = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                alert(players);
            }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you validated your JSON using JSONLint or some other service?

Comment: Problably something is outputed before echoing json encode

Comment: Look at the Net tab of your browser's developer looks. The output you are getting isn't what you expect.

Comment: Does the script have a `.php` extension? It sounds like the server isn't running the script, but is just returning it raw.

Comment: If you go to the ajax URL directly, check the Network tab in your browser console, or just `console.log(xhr.responseText)`, what does the response text look like?

Comment: Try `console.log(xhr.responseText)` to see whether you are getting right JSON on not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code produces a lot of warnings before printing the JSON output due to a missing $ in

```
$temparr[$fields[$i]] = $arr[i];
```

where

```
$arr[i]
```

should be

```
$arr[$i]
```

Comment: hm, right, that wouldn't produce a stray `<` ... but it is a problem you need to fix nonetheless ...